# type of variable in Visual C#

Tags: c#, variables, c#-4.0

I am using DirectSound to record voice and save in binary code.

```
var problem = _dwCapBuffer.Read(offset, typeof(byte), LockFlag.None, _dwOutputBufferSize);
#"problem" is byte array arrcording to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb280844.aspx
```

but when I use "problem" in function like  `private string ByteArray_to_Hex(byte[] data)
ByteArray_to_Hex(problem)`, it show the error

```
the best overload method....has some valid argument
```

How can I solve this problem ( use the return value of `CaptureBuffer.Read` as `byte[]` ) ?

Comment: What is type of `problem`? I guess it is `int`

Comment: I mentioned it, accordiong to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb280844.aspx , it 's byte array.

Comment: `var problem = (byte[])dwCapBuffer.Read(...` Note it returns `Array` not `byte[]` If you're sure about it is `byte[]` cast it.

Comment: It's return array of byte since I wrote CaptureBuffer.Read(,typeof(byte),,,). Is byte[] differnt from array of byte ? Btw, tks for your help, I did it. Since I got many downvote, it maybe very simple question but I google it for an hour before asking this question :D

Comment: Before googling just pay attention to compiler what it says, and why? you'll get answer most of the time. If you can't google may find, if google also can't we're here :)

Comment: `Array` is the base class for all arrays. `byte[]`, `string[]` or `whatever[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb280844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it's not returning a byte array but an [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array).

Just type `ByteArray_to_Hex(problem)` and let Visual Studio generate the method. Then you'll see what type it returns. Perhaps you can call `ByteArray_to_Hex((byte[])problem)` to explicitly cast it.